# start browser at an anchor possibly using a tag

Tags: html, browser, fortran, tags, anchor

I am developing an interactive software for thermodynamic calculations using an html help file with "anchor/target" features to select the appropriate part of the help file when the user types a ? as answer to a question.
This works well but at present a new browser window is opened each time the user types a "?".  I would prefer to start a new tag if there already is a browser window opened.

At present my program activate the help by creating a character with the content: `browser "file:helpfile#target"`
and then call the Fortran subroutine `execute_system_command(character)`.

"browser" can be firefox or whatever is the preferred browser by the user (on Mac including path);
"helpfile" contains the path and name of the my html help file;
"target" is a text which depend on the question asked by the software to localize the appropriate help text.

How can I modify this so I open a new tag in the browser (if it is already opened) rather than starting a new browser window?
Maybe something like "target=_blank" can be added?

My program is written in the new Fortran standard so I have no facilities that might be available in Java or Python.  It must work using different browsers on different OS.

Comment: Please show some code you already have, especially in respect to how you do open the html file (Note html help is a bit confusing as this points to the htmlhelp / chm type of files).

Comment: Regarding the: Maybe something like "target=_blank" can be added? I think this is / might be a setting of your browser.

Comment: Do you mean a new tab? This is really up to each user's browser settings. Doing `xdg-open https://...` does open a new tab for me. Or what do you mean by a tag?

Answer (score 0):

As @Vladimir pointed out I ment a "tab", there are so many terms.  But the answers I had made me reconsider which browser I could use.  And I made some new discoveries.

On Windows I used the old Explorer because the path to Firefox contains a space and when I tried to start Firefox to open a file
I had to enclose "C:\Program ...\firefox" within double quotes. That works to start the browser but if I want the browser to open a file I must enclose that also within double quote and that did not work.  I am not sure if the problem was the Fortran intrinsic EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE(txt) or deeper down.  But the old Explorer I could start without "" and just enclose "file:/help.html" with "".

So now I tried to be smart wrote a test program enclosing just the directories with a space within using "" i.e.
C:"Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"\firefox.exe "file:/help.html"
in the call to EXEXUTE...
and that worked and opened the helpfile in a tab as is my default.

Problem solved? No, when I had exchanged the browser with path in the program and tested it did not find the browser. The reason was that I have a test that the browser exist using another Fortran intrinsic INQUIRE and as I understand doublequotes are not legal inside file names so INQUIRE did not find firefox when there are " inside the path.  Only if " are used around the whole file name it worked.  So back to square one? No, I simply removed the " in the path+browser before calling INQUIRE, then used the path with "" inside when calling EXECTUE ...

and now it everything works as I wanted!